# Mongoid Relations (Custom accessors)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model, associations, mongoid

I am using Mongoid in my Rails app. I have a **User** model and I also have a **Role** model (think Admin, guest etc).

I want to setup my Mongoid associations such that the following code will be possible:

```
u = User.first
u.invited_roles # returns all roles a user has been assigned

r = Role.new
r.invitee = user # user id should be stored in the Role
r.save!
```

Currently, my models are set up as so:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :invited_roles, :class_name => 'Role'
end

class Role
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_one :invitee, :class_name => 'User'
end
```

Currently, when I do `Role.new` from the Rails console, I get an object that does not appear to have a field to store the invitee User. How do I fix this? I have seen people using inverse_of but I can't really find any tutorials or documentation on this procedure.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, thinking about this --- a User will be invited to have many roles, but that role will only have one user. Now, this is not "have one" in the sense of has_one. Instead, it's defining a child relationship.

So, change the has_one to belongs_to and you're golden.

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :invited_roles, :class_name => 'Role'
end

class Role
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :invitee, :class_name => 'User'
end
```